# Valediction for a team / group

Tags: writing, formal-language

I am writing a letter starting with 'Dear recruiting team,' (multiple recipients, not addressed by name).

Is 'Yours faithfully' the proper valediction for ending this letter?

Edit: It is for a British company.

Comment: Traditional British usage for a business letter is to use _Yours faithfully_ when writing to an _individual_ whose name you don't know. It depends how formal you intend your letter to be. Do you know some of these people, or is it something like a job application?

Comment: It is for a job application, none of the recipients are known to me. I intend the letter to be as formal as possible.

Comment: We had a temp in our legal office who used to start emails to senior judges starting 'Hi Judge' and ending 'Best wishes'. One complained to the manager, and she was told to be more formal. Soon, three other judges called to ask if they had offended her in some way, as she seemed to have grown cold towards them.

Comment: Those 'rules' such as 'Dear Sir... Yours faithfully'/Dear Mrs Smith...Yours sincerely' are so old-fashioned now in the UK that few recipients will know which is right, and still fewer will care. The content of the letter is the important thing. I have had a look at this UK page [How to Address a Letter to a Company](https://uk.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-address-a-letter-to-a-company) and it offers good advice.

Comment: I'm British, and the rule is that when addressing it to someone whose name you know, it's "Yours sincerely". If you are addressing it to someone whose name you don't know.  e.g. "Dear Sir/Madam" or "To whom it may concern", then it's "Yours faithfully". However, if you personally know all of the members of the recruiting team, but are addressing it to "Dear recruiting team" for brevity, then I'm not sure what the rule would be, and I'm finding it difficult to find an authoritative answer for that question. If you don't know them all personally, then it's definitely "Yours faithfully".

Comment: For some time now letters (snail mail) and emails that I receive have all sorts of closing salutations ranging from "Cheers" to "Yours sincerely" depending on how formal the content is. Hospital appointments - "Yours sincerely". My ISP service desk - "Kind regards" or just "Regards". Friends and family - "Cheers" or just "X". I've never heard of the sincerely / faithfully "rule" and suspect that there is no real justification. Somebody had to make it up even when there was no need. A bit like the discredited "Never end a sentence with a preposition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yours faithfully," is entirely formal, correct, and cannot possibly be considered inappropriate.

But don't spend too much time worrying about this.  While it is very important that your letter uses correct, standard spelling and grammar, the details of the valediction are not actually very important.  "Yours sincerely,"  "Sincerely, " or just "Yours," are entirely acceptable too.